# DST Entry time for few Timezone (Europe/Nicosia) are reporting wrong date using System.Globalization C#

Tags: c#, .net-core, timezone, mono, dst

I'm trying to get the DST entry time for the timezone "Antarctica/McMurdo" for the current year 2020 using System.Globalization class in C#. i'm receiving them as

```
DST Entry Time: 9/29/2020 2:00:00 AM
DST Exit Time: 4/5/2020 2:59:59 AM
```

But the actual DST entry time supposed to be on 9/27/2020 2:00:00 AM according to https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/antarctica/mcmurdo

The received entry time is already in DST because of which my test program is failing as the time shift is not happening.

Below is the code snippet used

```
var currTimeZone = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone;

var dstInfo = currTimeZone.GetDaylightChanges(now.Year);

DSTEntry = dstInfo.Start.ToString();
```

Below are the versions of Mono and Ubuntu i'm running on

Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Mono JIT compiler version 5.4.0.201

Here is the output of zdump

$ zdump  Antarctica/McMurdo -v 2019,2022

Antarctica/McMurdo  Sat Apr  6 13:59:59 2019 UT = Sun Apr  7 02:59:59 2019 NZDT isdst=1 gmtoff=46800

Antarctica/McMurdo  Sat Apr  6 14:00:00 2019 UT = Sun Apr  7 02:00:00 2019 NZST isdst=0 gmtoff=43200

Antarctica/McMurdo  Sat Sep 28 13:59:59 2019 UT = Sun Sep 29 01:59:59 2019 NZST isdst=0 gmtoff=43200

Antarctica/McMurdo  Sat Sep 28 14:00:00 2019 UT = Sun Sep 29 03:00:00 2019 NZDT isdst=1 gmtoff=46800

Antarctica/McMurdo  Sat Apr  4 13:59:59 2020 UT = Sun Apr  5 02:59:59 2020 NZDT isdst=1 gmtoff=46800

Antarctica/McMurdo  Sat Apr  4 14:00:00 2020 UT = Sun Apr  5 02:00:00 2020 NZST isdst=0 gmtoff=43200

Antarctica/McMurdo  Sat Sep 26 13:59:59 2020 UT = Sun Sep 27 01:59:59 2020 NZST isdst=0 gmtoff=43200

Antarctica/McMurdo  Sat Sep 26 14:00:00 2020 UT = Sun Sep 27 03:00:00 2020 NZDT isdst=1 gmtoff=46800

Antarctica/McMurdo  Sat Apr  3 13:59:59 2021 UT = Sun Apr  4 02:59:59 2021 NZDT isdst=1 gmtoff=46800

Antarctica/McMurdo  Sat Apr  3 14:00:00 2021 UT = Sun Apr  4 02:00:00 2021 NZST isdst=0 gmtoff=43200

Antarctica/McMurdo  Sat Sep 25 13:59:59 2021 UT = Sun Sep 26 01:59:59 2021 NZST isdst=0 gmtoff=43200

Antarctica/McMurdo  Sat Sep 25 14:00:00 2021 UT = Sun Sep 26 03:00:00 2021 NZDT isdst=1 gmtoff=46800

Can someone help me how to resolve this timing issue? or is this a bug from DLL/timezone_database which C# is reading from?

Thanks

Comment: Can you tell us what platform you're on? The use of `TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone` (rather than finding a system time zone by ID) makes it hard to tell. If you're using Windows, it's possible that the Windows time zone data is just wrong. If you're on a Unix box, the next step would be to look at the time zone files on the machine. One option would be to use my [NodaTime](https://nodatime.org) library instead, which gets this right, of course :)

Comment: Jon, i'm running this program on Linux platform using Mono. So, can you please suggest me from where the .net library reads these timezone information in Linux? i've examined "strings /usr/share/zoneinfo/NZ" 
 which is for Antartica/McMurdo timezone, i found the below entry" NZST-12NZDT,M9.5.0,M4.1.0/3".  According to this DST entry is supposed to be 5th week of Sep (on Sunday).  NodaTime library support is not there in our environment. So, can't use it.

Comment: Well if you're using Mono, it may well not be at all the same as if you're using .NET Core - that will depend on the version of Mono you're using. Please could you clarify? (Also, do you see the same thing if you use .NET Core instead of Mono?) Not sure what you mean by "NodaTime library support is not there in our environment. So, can't use it." It's just a library - do you mean you can't third party libraries? Given how much of this is going to be context-specific, it would really help if you'd give a *lot* more detail in the question. (Which flavour of Linux, and which version? Ditto mono)

Comment: Additionally, if you could run `zdump -i Antarctica/McMurdo -c 2019,2022` and include the output of that in the question, it would help.

Comment: Please *edit the question* with all this information, instead of using just adding comments. (It's much harder to read in comments, and comments should all be seen as transient - this information is crucial for answering the question.)

Comment: It sounds like you're using a version of Mono from 2017 though - I wouldn't be surprised if this were a bug that had been fixed in later versions. I'd definitely try that.

Comment: Okay, so it looks like the time zone files on your machine are okay. I'd try with a newer version of Mono (either v6 or the latest stable v5) to see if that fixes things - and ideally with .NET Core as well. I realize you may not easily be able to change version, but this will help pinpoint where the problem is.

Comment: I just tested with .net core and it is showing the DST entry time Correctly.

Comment: Okay. It's presumably a Mono bug then - so it would be good to know if it's *still* a bug, or whether it's been fixed. Then you can take appropriate action, e.g. working around it, using Noda Time, or upgrading.

Comment: No, i just tested on .net core to make sure it works on windows. You mean it works with mono version 6.x.x? Need a workaround for this mono version atleast.

Comment: "No, i just tested on .net core to make sure it works on windows." I meant on Linux, on the machine that it's failing on with Mono 5.4. But I'm asking *you* to test whether it works with Mono version 6.x.x. As I said before "it would be good to know if it's still a bug, or whether it's been fixed."

Comment: @Jon, I've tested with Mono version 6.4.0.198 and with that also i'm getting wrong DST entry for the timezone Auckland (new zealand). It is returning DST entry as 29th Sep 2020. But it is supposed to be 27th Sep 2020.  Yes, it is still a bug and needs to be fixed.

Comment: In that case I suggest you file a bug in the Mono repo, with a [mcve]. As for how to proceed - while I'm biased, I'd suggest that moving to Noda Time is likely to not only get past this problem, but make all your date/time code clearer. That's the hope, anyway.

Comment: OK. Fine. Thanks for guiding me all the way.

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation on the `TimeZone`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.timezone) class:

> Warning
>
> This API is now obsolete

...

> ⓘ Important
>
> Whenever possible, use the `TimeZoneInfo` class instead of the `TimeZone`
> class.

...

> The `TimeZone` class supports only a single daylight saving time
> adjustment rule for the local time zone. As a result, the `TimeZone`
> class can accurately report daylight saving time information or
> convert between UTC and local time only for the period in which the
> latest adjustment rule is in effect. In contrast, the `TimeZoneInfo`
> class supports multiple adjustment rules, which makes it possible to
> work with historic time zone data.

In short, ***don't use the `TimeZone` class***.